# R- Problem with Rcpp and Amelia R packages

Tags: r, rcpp

I recently updated Amelia to the most recent version 1.8.0, built: 2021-05-26.
Now, when I try to use the amelia() function, I get the error

```
Error in emarch(x.stacked$x, p2s = p2s, thetaold = NULL, tolerance = tolerance,  : 
  function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
```

I updated Rcpp, but it was not solved.
Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I first had to uninstall and reinstall (rather than update) the Rcpp package.
Problem solved now!